# ¿Por que me dice que la función no está definida?

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando mejoras en el código de PHP de una aplicación, y mi código es el siguiente:

```
function get_user_by_id($id, $table_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $query_select = "SELECT Id, name FROM $table_name WHERE Id =" . $id;

    $resultado_fila = $wpdb->get_results($query_select);


    $texto = $resultado_fila[0]->name;
    if (!is_null($resultado_fila)) {
  
        create_menu_to_synchronize($texto, $table_name, $id);

 

    }

    function create_menu_to_synchronize($text, $table_name, $id)
    {
    echo"
        <form id='form1' method='post'>
            <div>
                <button name='btnActualizar' id='btnActualizar' class='page title-action'>Actualizar</button>

            </div>
            <br><br>
            <hr>

            <label for='newName'><strong>Actualice su nombre:</strong></label>
            <br>
            
            <input type='date' name='newName' id='newName' style='width:100%' placeholder='$text'>
            
            <br>
            <hr>
        </form>";

      

        if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
            $new_name = $_POST['newName'];
            update_name($table_name,$new_name,$id);

        }



    }
```

Lo que pretendo es que cada vez que se pulse el botón, aparezca un pequeño formulario, para actualizar el nombre. La función que se usa para actualizar es:

```
function update_name($table_name, $lastName, $id)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,

        array(
            'name' => $lastName,

        ),

        array('Id' => $id)
    );
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que cada vez que llega a la llamada de `create_menu_to_synchronize`, dentro de `get_user_by_id` me aparece el mensaje de error:

> "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> create_menu_to_synchronize()..."

¿Por qué me aparece este error, si la función SI está definida? Gracias de antemano, y feliz año nuevo.

Comment: Parece que la segunda función está definida dentro de la primera...

Answer (score 2):

Como estoy viendo tu código, es una función dentro de otra función, en este caso, debes definir la función `create_menu_to_synchronize`, antes de llamarla, es decir, puedes colocarla al inicio de la función `get_user_by_id` para que cuando se haga el llamado, ya este creada.

```php
    <?php

function get_user_by_id($id, $table_name)
{
    function create_menu_to_synchronize($text, $table_name, $id)
    {
        echo "
        <form id='form1' method='post'>
            <div>
                <button name='btnActualizar' id='btnActualizar' class='page title-action'>Actualizar</button>

            </div>
            <br><br>
            <hr>

            <label for='newName'><strong>Actualice su nombre:</strong></label>
            <br>

            <input type='date' name='newName' id='newName' style='width:100%' placeholder='$text'>

            <br>
            <hr>
        </form>";

        if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
            $new_name = $_POST['newName'];
            update_name($table_name, $new_name, $id);
        }
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $query_select = "SELECT Id, name FROM $table_name WHERE Id =" . $id;

    $resultado_fila = $wpdb->get_results($query_select);

    $texto = $resultado_fila[0]->name;
    if (!is_null($resultado_fila)) {
        create_menu_to_synchronize($texto, $table_name, $id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente. Se trataba de un problema de cierre de llaves. ¡Feliz año 2022!

Answer (score 0):

Se trataba simplemente de un problema de cierre de llaves- de funciones. No había cerrado correctamente las llaves de la primera función. Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Por favor, no uses el area de respuestas para agregar comentarios.

Comment: Si ese era el problema, entonces te sugiero que elimines la pregunta, es un error tipográfico